# Cuda Kernel with different array sizes

Tags: cuda

I am working on a fluid dynamic problem in cuda and discovered a problem like this

if I have an array e.g debug_array with the length 600 and an array 
value_array with the length 100 and I wanna do sth like

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
   debug_array[6*(bx*block_size+tx)+i] = value_array[bx*block_size+tx];
}
```

block_size would in this example be based on the 100 element array, e.g 
4 blocks block_size 25

if value_array contains e.g 10;20;30;..... 
I would expect debug_array to have groups of 6 similar values like 
10;10;10;10;10;10;20;20;20;20;20;20;30......
The problem is that it is not picking up all values from the values array, any idea 
why this isn't working or a good workaround.

What will work is if I define float val = value_array[bx*block_size+tx]; outside the for loop and keep this inside the loop debug_array[bx*block_size+tx+i] = val;

But I would like to avoid that as my kernels have between 5 and 10 device function inside the loop and it makes it just hard to read.

thanks in advance any advice will be appriciated

Markus

Comment: To narrow this down further, please update the question with a complete kernel function that fails, and show its output, and a complete kernel function that succeeds, and show its output, and show how you're calling each. This will help others exactly reproduce your problem without having to make guesses about how you wrote the code.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error in computing the index:

Let's assume  `bx = 0` and `tx = 0`
The first 6 elements in debug_array will be filled with data.

Next thread: `tx = 1`: Elements 1 to 7 will be filled with data (overwriting existing data).
Due to the threads working in parallel it is not determined which thread will be scheduled first and therefore which values will be written into the debug_array.

You should have written:

```
 debug_array[6*(bx*block_size+tx)+i] = value_array[bx*block_size+tx];
```

Comment: Yes sorry missed that but I got it in my code, so that is not the problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If changing the code to move the value_array expression out of the loop and into a temp variable makes the code work - and that is the only code change you made - then this smells like a compiler bug.

Try changing your nvcc compiler options to reduce or disable optimizations and see if the value_array expression inside the loop changes behavior.  Also, make sure you're using the latest CUDA tools.

Optimizing compilers will often attempt to move expressions that aren't dependent on the loop index variable out of the loop, exactly like your manual workaround. It's called "invariant code motion" and it makes loops faster by reducing the amount of code that executes in each iteration of the loop. If manually extracting the invariant code from the loop works, but letting the compiler figure it out on its own doesn't, that casts doubt on the compiler.